# How to add invoice pdf as a custom column?

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, invoice-pdf

[image]I want to add custom column in pdf magento how i can add?
And where the location to add custom column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the below file:

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

and copy the method **insertOrder** with code from

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php

to your overridden **Invoice.php**

Then find the Payment Block and add your code there like below. Find the block:

```
foreach ($payment as $value){
    if (trim($value) != '') {
        //Printing "Payment Method" lines
        $value = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', "\n", $value);
        foreach (Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
            $page->drawText(strip_tags(trim($_value)), $paymentLeft, $yPayments, 'UTF-8');
            $yPayments -= 15;
        }
    }
}
```

and add the following code just after the above block:

```
$page->drawText(strip_tags('Custom Section'), $paymentLeft, $yPayments, 'UTF-8');
$yPayments -= 15;
```

Comment: i want to add in payemnt section and want to rewrite abstract class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract is it possible

Comment: You cannot override abstract class. In your question you have asked that you need to column. Please explain in detail with screenshot in your question.

Comment: i have create column in my sales flat order table its name ref no its store any value now i want to show it in my pdf in payment method section after payment

Comment: Can you add any screenshot how would it looks?

Comment: done i want after there as i mentioned i color

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: it working invoice what about shipment?i need to rewrite ?

Comment: Same for shipment. Override the Shipment.php instead of Invoice.php and do the same thing.